# Is there a way to conduct a calculation on dataframe using datapoints on different rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this might be very simple calculation but I'm lost how to put this on a loop, in case where there is a very long list of same cases. I want to return a loop result that calculates the

(Special Amount - Normal Amount) / Normal Amount

For each Names.

So for example,

```
d = {'name': [A, A, B, B], 'Type': ['normal','special','normal','special'], 'Amount': [11.45, 7.5, 40, 10]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

so for df, I currently have something like

| name | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Normal | 11.45 |
| A | Special | 7.5 |
| B | Normal | 40 |
| B | Special | 10 |

What I have tried is, first using groupby

```
df['difference'] = df.groupby('name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

and I get

| name | Type | Amount | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Normal | 11.45 | 0 |
| A | Special | 7.5 | -3 |
| B | Normal | 40 | 0 |
| B | Special | 10 | -30 |

But now, I'm stuck on how to write (or possibly for loop) that does the calculation

Difference / Normal amount

for each names... as you see the last chart, the calculation goes diagonal so I can't just do

```
df['Result'] = df['Amount'] / df['Difference']
```

Is there a good way to do this calculation??
I would appreciate any help! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'name': ["A", "A", "B", "B"], 'Type': ['normal','special','normal','special'], 'Amount': [11.45, 7.5, 40, 10]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['relative_difference'] = 0.0
for name in np.unique(df['name']):
    special_amount = float(df[df["name"]==name][df[df["name"]==name]["Type"] == "special"]["Amount"])
    normal_amount = float(df[df["name"]==name][df[df["name"]==name]["Type"] == "normal"]["Amount"])
    df.loc[df['name']==name,'relative_difference'] = float((special_amount - normal_amount)/normal_amount)
df
```

| name | Type | Amount | relative_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | normal | 11.45 | -0.344978 |
| A | special | 7.50 | -0.344978 |
| B | normal | 40.00 | -0.750000 |
| B | special | 10.00 | -0.750000 |

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
def calc(df):
    s = df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index('Type')['Amount']
    return (s.special - s.normal) / s.normal

df.groupby('name').apply(calc)

# name
# A   -0.344978
# B   -0.750000
# dtype: float64
```

And if you want to have the result back in the original dataframe:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('name').apply(calc).rename('Result').to_frame().reset_index(),how='left',on='name')

#   name     Type  Amount    Result
# 0    A   normal   11.45 -0.344978
# 1    A  special    7.50 -0.344978
# 2    B   normal   40.00 -0.750000
# 3    B  special   10.00 -0.750000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simpliest is first pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), and then count values:

```
df1 = df.pivot('name','Type','Amount')

df1['Result'] = (df1['special'] - df1['normal']) / df1['normal']
print (df1)
Type  normal  special    Result
name                           
A      11.45      7.5 -0.344978
B      40.00     10.0 -0.750000
```

Last for add to original use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1['Result'], on='name')
print (df)
  name     Type  Amount    Result
0    A   normal   11.45 -0.344978
1    A  special    7.50 -0.344978
2    B   normal   40.00 -0.750000
3    B  special   10.00 -0.750000
```

If dont need column `Result` in `df1`:

```
df1 = df.pivot('name','Type','Amount')

s = (df1['special'] - df1['normal']) / df1['normal']
print (s)
name
A   -0.344978
B   -0.750000
dtype: float64

df = df.join(s.rename('Result'), on='name')
print (df)
  name     Type  Amount    Result
0    A   normal   11.45 -0.344978
1    A  special    7.50 -0.344978
2    B   normal   40.00 -0.750000
3    B  special   10.00 -0.750000
```